# Getting element not found evern after finding the element and performng the action on the element

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor and i am getting an strange issue. I login and execute few tests and logout. Everything works fine here. I need to re-login to execute the same tests using another user id. second time even after user id and password are entered in their respective fields and login is done successfully but process exits without executing remaining test and i get error message. Below is my code and error i get

**code Snippet :**

```
ar testData = require('./Test Data/Users.json');

describe('SSUE Login', function() {

  it('Verifies user access', function() {


      browser.driver.get('https://url');
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      element(by.id('userInput')).sendKeys(testData[1].username);
      element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys(testData[1].passwordField);
      element(by.id('login-button')).click();
      browser.driver.sleep(9000);
      browser.waitForAngular();

      element(by.css('.AtlanticIcon_header_logout')).getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('Login Successful '+text+' icon visible in UI');

      });
      if(element(by.xpath('//div[@class="walkme-custom-balloon-content-wrapper"]')).isPresent().then(function(){
              element(by.xpath('//div[@class="walkme-custom-balloon-content-wrapper"]/div[1]')).click();
      }));

      browser.driver.sleep(2000);
      }
  }, 90000);
});
```

**Below is my config file**
Notice I login and execute 6 test. In last of 6 tests **'gridFilter.js'** i have a logout action. Next i Login again using another user id through **'login2.js'**. User is successfully loged in but the next test after login does not execute and browser repeatedly loads on its own and finally process exits and get results output in json and I am also adding the result in the end

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress   : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs             : ['login.js', 'userType.js', 'globalFilterOptions.js', 'languageTest.js', 'loadDatagrid.js', 'datagridicons.js', 'gridFilter.js', 'login2.js', 'userType.js', 'globalFilterOptions.js', 'languageTest.js', 'loadDatagrid.js', 'datagridicons.js', 'gridFilter.js', 'login3.js', 'userType.js', 'globalFilterOptions.js', 'languageTest.js', 'loadDatagrid.js', 'datagridicons.js', 'gridFilter.js', 'login4.js', 'userType.js', 'globalFilterOptions.js', 'languageTest.js', 'loadDatagrid.js', 'datagridicons.js', 'gridFilter.js', 'login5.js', 'userType.js', 'globalFilterOptions.js', 'languageTest.js', 'loadDatagrid.js', 'datagridicons.js', 'gridFilter.js', 'login6.js', 'userType.js', 'globalFilterOptions.js', 'languageTest.js', 'loadDatagrid.js', 'datagridicons.js', 'gridFilter.js'],
  // Exclude files if needed
  exclude: [],


  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
  rootElement: 'html',

  framework         : 'jasmine2',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    ,print: function() {}
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
    // add jasmine spec reporter
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: true}));
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    var JSONReporter = require('jasmine-json-test-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new JSONReporter({
        file: 'SSUE-Daily-Satus-Report.json',
        beautify: true,
        indentationLevel: 4 // used if beautify === true 
    }));
},


  // An array of capability objects
  multiCapabilities : [
    {
      browserName : 'chrome'

      // Add another set of specs for this browser only
      // specs: []
    }
  ]
};
```

**Here is the test results that i am converted to JSON**

```
"suite1": {
    "id": "suite1",
    "description": "SSUE Login",
    "fullName": "SSUE Login",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec0",
            "description": "Verifies user access",
            "fullName": "SSUE Login Verifies user access",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite2": {
    "id": "suite2",
    "description": "User Details:",
    "fullName": "User Details:",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec1",
            "description": "User type and id",
            "fullName": "User Details: User type and id",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite3": {
    "id": "suite3",
    "description": "Global Filter:",
    "fullName": "Global Filter:",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec2",
            "description": "Displays User entitled customers and inventories",
            "fullName": "Global Filter: Displays User entitled customers and inventories",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite4": {
    "id": "suite4",
    "description": "Langauge Selection : ",
    "fullName": "Langauge Selection : ",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec3",
            "description": "Test check the language options",
            "fullName": "Langauge Selection :  Test check the language options",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite5": {
    "id": "suite5",
    "description": "Datagrid Load Test :",
    "fullName": "Datagrid Load Test :",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec4",
            "description": "Datagrid Clickable in LNP",
            "fullName": "Datagrid Load Test : Datagrid Clickable in LNP",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite6": {
    "id": "suite6",
    "description": "Datagrid Icons :",
    "fullName": "Datagrid Icons :",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec5",
            "description": "Displayed after the grid loads",
            "fullName": "Datagrid Icons : Displayed after the grid loads",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite7": {
    "id": "suite7",
    "description": "Group Filter Test ",
    "fullName": "Group Filter Test ",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec6",
            "description": "Testing filtering groups",
            "fullName": "Group Filter Test  Testing filtering groups",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite8": {
    "id": "suite8",
    "description": "SSUE Login",
    "fullName": "SSUE Login",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec7",
            "description": "Verifies user access",
            "fullName": "SSUE Login Verifies user access",
            "failedExpectations": [],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite9": {
    "id": "suite9",
    "description": "SSUE Login",
    "fullName": "SSUE Login",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec8",
            "description": "Verifies user access",
            "fullName": "SSUE Login Verifies user access",
            "failedExpectations": [
                {
                    "matcherName": "",
                    "message": "Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id=\"userInput\"])",
                    "stack": "NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id=\"userInput\"])\n    at WebDriverError (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\error.js:27:10)\n    at NoSuchElementError (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\error.js:242:10)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:808:27\n    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1379:14)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2913:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2896:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2775:27\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:639:7\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)Error\n    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:461:27)\n    at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:103:30)\n    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:829:22)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Protector\\SSUE_Daily_Status\\login3.js:11:35)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:94:23\n    at new ManagedPromise (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1082:7)\n    at controlFlowExecute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:80:18)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2913:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2896:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2820:25\nFrom: Task: Run it(\"Verifies user access\") in control flow\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:79:14)\n    at attemptAsync (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1916:24)\n    at QueueRunner.run (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1871:9)\n    at QueueRunner.execute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1859:10)\n    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:697:35)\n    at Spec.execute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:359:10)\n    at Object.fn (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:2479:37)\n    at attemptAsync (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1916:24)\n    at QueueRunner.run (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1871:9)\n    at QueueRunner.execute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1859:10)\nFrom asynchronous test: \nError\n    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\\Protector\\SSUE_Daily_Status\\login3.js:6:3)\n    at addSpecsToSuite (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:833:25)\n    at Env.describe (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:802:7)\n    at jasmineInterface.describe (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:3375:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Protector\\SSUE_Daily_Status\\login3.js:4:1)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
                    "passed": false,
                    "expected": "",
                    "actual": ""
                }
            ],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "failed"
        }
    ]
},
"suite10": {
    "id": "suite10",
    "description": "SSUE Login",
    "fullName": "SSUE Login",
    "failedExpectations": [],
    "status": "finished",
    "specs": [
        {
            "id": "spec9",
            "description": "Verifies user access",
            "fullName": "SSUE Login Verifies user access",
            "failedExpectations": [
                {
                    "matcherName": "",
                    "message": "Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id=\"userInput\"])",
                    "stack": "NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id=\"userInput\"])\n    at WebDriverError (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\error.js:27:10)\n    at NoSuchElementError (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\error.js:242:10)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:808:27\n    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1379:14)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2913:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2896:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2775:27\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:639:7\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)Error\n    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:461:27)\n    at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:103:30)\n    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\element.js:829:22)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Protector\\SSUE_Daily_Status\\login4.js:13:35)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:94:23\n    at new ManagedPromise (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1082:7)\n    at controlFlowExecute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:80:18)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2913:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2896:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2820:25\nFrom: Task: Run it(\"Verifies user access\") in control flow\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:79:14)\n    at attemptAsync (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1916:24)\n    at QueueRunner.run (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1871:9)\n    at QueueRunner.execute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1859:10)\n    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:697:35)\n    at Spec.execute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:359:10)\n    at Object.fn (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:2479:37)\n    at attemptAsync (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1916:24)\n    at QueueRunner.run (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1871:9)\n    at QueueRunner.execute (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1859:10)\nFrom asynchronous test: \nError\n    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\\Protector\\SSUE_Daily_Status\\login4.js:6:3)\n    at addSpecsToSuite (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:833:25)\n    at Env.describe (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:802:7)\n    at jasmineInterface.describe (C:\\Users\\surbhat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine\\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:3375:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Protector\\SSUE_Daily_Status\\login4.js:4:1)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
                    "passed": false,
                    "expected": "",
                    "actual": ""
                }
            ],
            "passedExpectations": [],
            "pendingReason": "",
            "status": "failed"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: can you provide code that does login for both user 1 and 2?

Comment: What version of Protractor are you on? Also, if you are using ignoreSynchronization you also have to provide your own timeouts and waiting OR nest them in a then statements.

Comment: my both logins have the same code

Comment: element(by.id('userInput')).sendKeys(testData[1].username);
element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys(testData[1].passwordField);

Comment: just the user name and password are got from json file "testData.json" So the number 0 in testData[0].username is used to get first user and testData[1].username is used to get next user.

Comment: Also to answer the protractor version, I am using 4.0.14

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [`browser.pause`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.pause) in your code and see what state your browser is in. You might notice that you are still logged in or the user name input doesn't exist (maybe the app's workflow remembers the username). This cannot be concluded from either your code or your stacktrace but trying it out.

This is what I would try:

- navigate to the login page
- login with user 0
- logout
- browser.pause and inspect the state of the browser

---

Something like:

```
describe('login and logout', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // navigate to login page
  });

  it('should be logged in user 0', () => {
    element(by.id('userInput')).sendKeys(testData[0].username);
    element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys(testData[0].passwordField);
    element(by.id('login-button')).click();

    // assertions about logging in
    // process to log out
    // assertions about logging out
  });

  // this spec should not run but we'll leave it in.
  it('should be logged in user 1', () => {
    element(by.id('userInput')).sendKeys(testData[1].username);
    element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys(testData[1].passwordField);
    element(by.id('login-button')).click();

    // assertions about logging in
    // process to log out
    // assertions about logging out
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // stop here to see what's going on with your browser.
    // in the window, navigate to your login page. possibly your
    // username input does not exist for various reasons. maybe this 
    // is a bug.
    browser.pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I have  different situation than what you suspected here. I have to run few test cases on various login Id's . (like login1, test 1, test2, test 3 logout and then login 2, test 1, test2 ,test 3, logout and then login 3 ....).

Comment: So i login first time and execute test 1, test2, test3 ..... I then logout and login again. everything works fine till here. I see the login window and user id and password are also entered that I am passing from a json file. second user is loged in also but after a while script exits and error is sent to a json file that i am using to capture the test results. error is about that login input text box wasn't found where as script has already sent key for this element and even clicked login button

Comment: Well, I think you need to improve your question. Include your configuration file, a simple code snippet that you are getting this error from. Also include the browser name, browser version, browser drivers, operating system, node version, protractor version, and things you have tried. My reply looks unhelpful because I'm guessing at your problem and my recommendation was to debug.

Comment: I just added the config file and results json

Comment: The code snippet provided is not enough. Please add that as well.

Comment: added the login code that is causing the error second time

Comment: Last question, is this an AngularJS app, an AngularJS/Angular hybrid, Angular app or none of the above?

Comment: yes it is an angular app. Just login page is non angular because there is a single login for all applications across the company